# Cannot convert value of type 'NSAttributedString.DocumentAttributeKey' to expected dictionary key type 'NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey'

Tags: swift, xcode, nsattributedstring, swift4, nsattributedstringkey

I have just updated to Xcode 9 and converted my app from swift 3 to swift 4 and get this errors. how i can fix this?

```
 func displayText() {
    do {
        if url.pathExtension.lowercased() != "rtf" {
            let fileContent = try String(contentsOf: url)
            text.text = fileContent
        } else { // Is RTF file
            let attributedString = try NSAttributedString(url: url, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSRTFTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil)
            text.attributedText = attributedString
            text.isEditable = false
        }
    }
```

**And get this Error**

> Cannot convert value of type 'NSAttributedString.DocumentAttributeKey' to expected dictionary key type 'NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey'

Answer (score 4):

In swift 4 - NSAttributedString representation is completely changed.

Replace your attribute dictionary key and value `[NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSRTFTextDocumentType]`with `[NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType : NSAttributedString.DocumentType.rtf]`

Try this:

```
func displayText() {
    do {
        if url.pathExtension.lowercased() != "rtf" {
            let fileContent = try String(contentsOf: url)
            text.text = fileContent
        } else { // Is RTF file
            let attributedString = try NSAttributedString(url: url, options: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType : NSAttributedString.DocumentType.rtf], documentAttributes: nil)
            text.attributedText = attributedString
            text.isEditable = false
        }
    }
}
```

Here is note from Apple: [NSAttributedString - Creating an NSAttributedString Object](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring)